# How to transpose a unique list of values from a column using 'CopyToRange'

Tags: vba, excel

After some research I've found ways to transpose using 'pastespecial'. However, I don't think this will work for me since I'm using copy to range to get unique values.

The following code works in copying unique values to a workbook:

```
Sub GetComponents()

ActiveSheet.Range("G2:G65536").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"), Unique:=True

End Sub
```

However, when I try to transpose it fails

```
Sub GetComponents()

ActiveSheet.Range("G2:G65536").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"), Unique:=True, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Is there a way To get 'CopyToRange' to transpose? If not can I get 'PasteSpecial' to filter on unique values?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way is to do it in 2 steps:

```
Sub GetComponents()

ActiveSheet.Range("G2:G65536").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _ 
     CopyToRange:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"), Unique:=True

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Copy
    .Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    .Columns("A").EntireColumn.Delete
End With

End Sub
```